# Persistant Storage in HTML5 for Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a blackberry app through HTML5 Webworks and am looking for a way to persistanty store a series of strings. For example, assume I have a list of names

- Anna
- Bob
- Cathy
- David
- Erin
- Fred
- George

if I click on one of their names, I want to store them in a "favourites" section. So if I click on Anna, Bob and Fred I would like to persistently store them. Having turned the phone on and off, I would hope to see on the favourites section:

- Anna
- Bob
- Fred

So far I apparently have two options: HTML5 localStorage API or the WebSQL Database.

1.) [localStorage](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#async_transactions)
2.) [WebSQL Database](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#async_transactions)

I'm very new to HTML5 and web development so I'm not sure which, if either, is the right choice to use in my case. I'm looking for something fairly simple to use as I'm not too competent yet on webworks. Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks for any information.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), Chapter 7, Local Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` would probably work best in this situation. To my knowledge, it has more browser support, and it's far simpler to use.

You can learn more about it here:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

Comment: But one thing I'm thinking about localStorage is that you need a different key everytime you add on to it. So if I would be managing a list of favourites, i.e. adding and deleting, wouldn't some sort of array be better? Because the keys favourite1, favourite2, favourite3 go on, but what happens if I need to delete favourite2 and then I want to add another element later. I would have to somehow search all the favourites by string value to see which are set to "" (cleared) and then replace the values.

Comment: localStorage is more of a hash table than an array (though it does share an array's functionality). You can remove items with the `localStorage.removeItem(key)` function.

Answer (score 4):

This site may help you: http://caniuse.com/#index

It seems web storage is supported well: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage.

No mention of blackberry-webworks though.

Comment: BlackBerry OS 6 and higher supports HTML5 local storage.  This includes the PlayBook Tablet OS and the new BlackBerry 10.  Actually, you can get localStorage to 'work' on BlackBerry OS 5.0, but you need to use a shim http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Supporting-Gears-using-HTML5-in-BlackBerry-WebWorks-applications/ta-p/557280